# Making Maven command line parameter mandatory

Tags: java, spring, maven, command-line

I'm writing a small project to learn about Maven and Spring Framework. To run my project I run following command:

```
clean install exec:java -e -DinputFolder=src/main/resources/testCases
```

Is there a way to make inputFolder parameter mandatory when running this?

Thanks.

Comment: First of all: What do you really want to achieve? Do you want to run tests? Why do you put them into src/main/resources?

Comment: Secondly: You can add plugin executions to your pom. Then they are automatically called when the build is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Maven Enforcer Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) can be used to require properties to be configured for your build.  The [requireProperty](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html) rule will do the job.

`<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-property</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireProperty>
                  <property>inputFolder</property>
                  <message>inputFolder property must be set</message>
                </requireProperty>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>`